# Rails 4 Controller Test "Undefined Method Permit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple controller test based on the Rails 4 docs (using Test::Unit):

```
test "should create user" do
  assert_difference('User.count') do
    post :create, user: users(:sample_user)
  end
  assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user))
end
```

And, despite the actual user being created just fine, the test fails, saying:

> 1) Error:
>   UsersControllerTest#test_should_create_user:
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `permit' for "832959492":String
>       app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in`user_params'
>       app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'
>       test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:11:in`block (2 levels) in '
>       test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in '

For some reason, the test isn't recognizing the new Rails 4 `permit` method. Right now, I have the `user_params` as a private method in the controller. But, I tried moving it up to the actual `create` action and received the same error. The user creation is also 100% standard (nothing crazy at all- just like the Rails docs).

Does anyone know how I can rewrite or otherwise make this test pass?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems like the data that is being `POST`ed to your `create` route is just a string, instead of a hash of attributes.  What does `users(:sample_user)` return?  Is it just an ID, or maybe an ActiveRecord object that is not being serialized correctly?  If it's AR, maybe you need to send `users(:sample_user).attributes` as the payload?

Comment: Thanks, I was using a fixture and that was the problem. Adding .attributes was the solution!